# How would I configure FlyWay in IntegrationTest scope

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, flyway

I'm attempting to configure flyway differently when it's within the IntegrationTest configuration scope inside a subproject in `sbt`:

```scala
// build.sbt

lazy val api = Project.project.in(file("api")).
  // ...
  settings(flywaySettings: _*).
  settings(
    // ...
    flywayUrl in IntegrationTest := "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb_test"
    flywayUser in IntegrationTest := "user"
    flywayPassword in IntegrationTest := "pw"
 )
```

But when run from sbt it is still looking for the values in the default scope:

```bash
$ sbt

> api/it:flywayUrl
[info] jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb_test

> api/it:flywayUser
[info] user

> api/it:flywayPassword
[info] pw

> api/it:flywayMigrate
// ...
[info] Flyway 3.2.1 by Boxfuse
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last api/*:flywayMigrate for the full output.
[error] (api/*:flywayMigrate) org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to connect to the database. Configure the url, user and password!
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed 27-Jan-2016 1:33:08 PM
```

Not sure what I did wrong....

Comment: Looks like this was fixed but remains undeployed: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/763

Comment: I think this is not fixed, even in the unreleased 4.0.0 source: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/763#issuecomment-177636052

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I need to use `inConfig`:

```scala
// build.sbt
lazy val api = Project.project.in(file("api")).

// copy the settings into the IntegrationTest Configuration
settings(inConfig(IntegrationTest)(flywaySettings): _*).
settings(
  // ...
  flywayUrl in IntegrationTest := "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb_test"
  flywayUser in IntegrationTest := "user"
  flywayPassword in IntegrationTest := "pw"
),
```

Now the command `api/it:flywayMigrate` will get values from the correct scope.